# Does Shouldly have a statement like Assert.Fail()?

Tags: unit-testing, shouldly

Most unit testing frameworks have a method like [Fail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243700.aspx), which unconditionally throws an assertion exception.

Does Shouldly have this kind of instruction?

Comment: Are you using nunit as well? Why not just use Assert.Fail("Something bad happened")?

Comment: Not in this project, I'm not. If I were, I wouldn't ask this question.

Comment: @PawełG. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The question in its current state is also incomplete and therefore unclear. Read [ask] and then [edit] the question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: @PawełG.: Then remove the nunit tag.